# Debugging server application from client

Tags: c++, debugging, client-server, msdn

I am doing this sample https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx that contains a C++ tutorial for client and server with Winsock. To run this the server must be run before the client, obviously, but how to debug these things. I mean when I start the server and put a breakpoint in the main function it executes, but when I do this in the client I want to see the interraction with the server code from its solution. Im confused. Is there an article describing this?

Comment: Run two instances of Visual Studio, one where you debug the server and one where you debug the client?

Comment: Yes, thats what I do, but is there a way to transfer the debugging information in terms of breakpoitns from the one to another. How to handle these callbacks. I am new to this

Comment: Not really, you just have to step through the client until it has sent some data to the server or blocks, switch IDE and step through the server until it replies back to the client, and so on. It's tedious but no one said that programming (and debugging is a big part of programming) is easy. :)